# Spring Boot OAuth2 Authentication Login Page Correct Location And Access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm investigating Spring Security, and it's really becoming a pain in the ass for me. What I wanted was a simple authentication and authorization process.

I have some questions in my mind and I can't find the right answers to them. Could you please consider the following questions for a *Restful Web API* project and make them more meaningful for me?

1. How should we access the Login Page when we use Form Login or Authentication Server? For example: when it enters `domainname/login`, should we redirect it to `backenddomain/login` or `keycloak/login` and get username and password or should we make an `HTTP Post Request` like `x-www-form-urlencoded` to those addresses?
2. Why none of the examples on the internet do this through the backend project. I mean, can't we send a request to `backenddomain/api/login` and with the information we provide, Keycloak will verify the user and return a response?
3. Let's say we set up *AS*, does it make sense to upload our AS address from our client address? Why are we exposing these addresses to them that the person doesn't need to know? I look at the examples, I read the questions and I always see comments like showing the ready login page to the user or edit his theme, I don't understand.

I am someone who is trying to learn *Flutter*, I want to improve myself in Spring Boot and create a simple endpoint for myself to contribute to my Flutter learning, but I can't grasp these Security issues, I'm losing hope.

Comment: You have obviously not yet understood what Form login and OAuth2 are about. Both are pretty different and it's likely that neither work the way you expect. So I suggest you **get some background about the two before trying to implement either with Spring Security**. Once you understood those standards, open [Spring security manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/). (if you hold a brush by the hairs, you'll find painting pretty inefficient).

Comment: @ch4mp Thank you for your suggestion. I mentioned that example because they both have their own login url, I am aware that they are quite different. I am still learning, but the point I am trying to understand is that there are many websites and applications that use these structures. But when you want to log in, they don't redirect you to these urls. You stay in the client domain and enter the information. I wonder how this is done. If it is done using `x-www-form-urlencoded`, then I understand that functions like *remember me* cannot be used because of cookies.

Comment: You can have many host (OAuth2 actors) behind a single gateway. In that case you just don't see your requests are processed by an OAuth2 authorization server or an OAuth2 client and then an OAuth2 resource server, but it's actually what's happening when you use Gmail or Facebook or many many other web apps (including stackoverflow)